Projective varieties contained in dense open subsets
Let $X$ be a smooth irreducible projective variety over the complex numbers. Let $U$ be a nontrivial dense open subset of $X$.
Does there exist a projective curve $C$ inside $U$?
My attempt:
Let's start by saying that my naive guess is that no, I think in general a projective variety (not even a curve) cannot be contained inside $U$. The guess is motivated by two result I have studied:

An irreducible variety which is both projective and affine is a point
A curve minus a (finite number of) point is affine

However, I am not assuming $U$ is affine, but just open and dense.
I have thought about writing $U= \bigcup_{f} D^+(f)$, with $f$ homogeneous polynomials. Then every intersection $C\cap D^+(f)$ is affine, and I am removing some points $(q_i)_{i\in I}$ of $C$, but I cannot see how to conclude because such points may be contained in another intersection.

If the codimension of $X \setminus U$ in $X$ is larger than 1, there are many projective curves in $U$. But if the codimension is 1 and $X \setminus U$ is an ample divisor, there are no curves in $U$.

Dear @Sasha, thank you very much for your comment. If you have the time of converting your comment into an answer, maybe adding just a reference or a small explanation about what you said, I'll surely accept it!

Let $Z = X \setminus U$.
If $\operatorname{codim}_X(Z) \ge 2$, there are many projective curves in $U$. Indeed, if $\dim(X) = n$ and $X \subset \mathbb{P}^N$, then (by Bertini) a general complete intersection of $n - 1$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^N$ with $X$ is a curve which does not intersect $Z$, hence is contained in $U$.
But if $Z$ contains an ample divisor, any curve in $X$ intersects $Z$, hence there are no curves in $U$.
An example where $\operatorname{codim}_X(Z) = 1$ but $Z$ is not ample, is $X = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $Z = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \{\mathrm{point}\}$, hence $U = \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{A}^1$. In this case, of course, $U$ contains curves.

The answer will depend. Like you said, if $U$ is affine, then the answer is no. On the other hand, if $U$ is $\mathbb{P}^2$ with a point removed then any line that doesn’t contain that point is a projective curve contained in $U$.
Determining if there exists a projective curve inside of an open set can be interesting in some cases. For example it has been shown that there exists a projective curve inside of $\mathcal{M}_g$ (the moduli space of smooth curves of genus $g$) for all $g$. This is pretty hard and it is not even known what the highest dimension of a projective subvariety of $\mathcal{M}_g$ is.
